# `makefile` not working as expected

Tags: c, makefile

How can I have it so that when I run `make` that:

- `prog.s` is created then `prog` is created if `prog.s` and `prog` does not exist
- `prog.s` is created if `prog.s` is newer than `prog.c` (eg. after manually modifying `prog.s`)
- `prog.s` then `prog` is created if `prog.c` is newer than `prog`

In other words, have `make` create the files it needs to build `prog`, if the dependencies have been modified

My current makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS =
TARGET = prog

all: $(TARGET).s $(TARGET).c


$(TARGET).c: $(TARGET).s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).s -o $(TARGET)

$(TARGET).s:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $(TARGET).s $(TARGET).c


clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
    $(RM) $(TARGET).s
```

It works if I have:

- only `prog.c`
- manually modified `prog.s`

but does not work if I have manually modified `prog.c`
(`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define your `target: source` in the reversed order. For instance, your assembly code depends on your C code, you **must** write:

```
$(TARGET).s: $(TARGET).c
```

however, you have written (wrong order)

```
$(TARGET).c: $(TARGET).s
```

Here is the version with the **right order** for "target: sources" :

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS =
TARGET = prog

all: $(TARGET)


$(TARGET): $(TARGET).s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).s -o $(TARGET)

$(TARGET).s: $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S -o $(TARGET).s $(TARGET).c


clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
    $(RM) $(TARGET).s
```